# Same extension point id in two Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am implementing two plugins that references a third plugin project that has its own plugin.xml with several extensions points. Hence in my Eclipse environment I have two plugins that has mutual extensions point with the same id.
I've noticed that when I trigger the appearance of one of these mutual extensions point, Eclipse try to load the extension point arbitrary from any of these plugins (and not necessarily from the context of the plugin in which I am at its perspective), and I am getting a classcastexception in my code (as the extension point class is taken from another class loader).
Is there any way to control that extensions point will be loaded per the correct plugin/bundle?

Comment: This is rather unclear, I think you need to show an example. Extension point definition ids should be unique.

Comment: Is it mandatory that in the same eclipse environment, two plugins won't be sharing the same id for two extensions points?

Comment: If two plugins both declare the same extension point you get undefined behavior.

Comment: So what has one that wishes to create two plugins that share most of their views/editor/menus should do?

Comment: You use a third plugin with the common views/editors/menus.

Comment: We tried that but once a view, which is defined in the common plugin is opened within a perspective defined in plugin A, it cannot be used within a perspective defined in plugin B, as we are getting a class cast exception. The view class is loaded with the class loader for plugin A (and not the common plugin) and when referring it the 2nd time in the context of plugin B, it will load the class from plugin A class loader, and hence the exception,

Comment: That does not sound correct, with the correct dependencies and APIs you should not get that. Show us the code you are using.